# ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src' in

Tags: angularjs, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I am trying to add react components to angular1.5 project. 
I added to my wepback the path of first component this isnt starting with index.js its just jsx react component.
when I try to run my build I am getting error

> ```
> WARNING in configuration The 'mode' option has not been set, webpack will fallback to 'production' for this value. Set 'mode'
> ```
>
> option to 'development' or 'production' to enable defaults for each
>   environment. You can also set it to 'none' to disable any default
>   behavior. Learn more: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/mode/
>
> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src'

my code looks like

```
const path = require('path');
const config = require('./ENVIRONMENT_CONFIG_FOR_GULP/configConstants');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve('entryPoint.js'),
 mode: 'development',
    module: {
            rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          use: {
            loader: "babel-loader"
          }
        } 
    ]},
    output: {
        filename: config.webpackBundleFileName,
        path: path.resolve(config.src, 'modules')
    },
    devtool: "#source-map"
};
```

Comment: What is `entryPoint.js` in entry here?

Comment: Whats the name of your webpack config file?

Answer (score 0):

You have two issue in your configuration

First you havent set the mode of webpack yet

So to fix it add below script to your scripts section in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "prod": "webpack -p --mode=production",
    "start": "webpack --mode=development"
}
```

then run `npm run start` or `npm run prod`

Second issue try to use string for your path in this config

```
path: path.resolve(config.src, 'modules')
```

change to something like this

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "wwwroot/dist"),
    filename: "[name].js",
    publicPath: "/dist/"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the issue the plugin that I used was changed due to update packages versions:

the current code

```
  let compiler = webpack(webpackConfig);

    new webpack.ProgressPlugin().apply(compiler);

    return  compiler.run(function (err, stats) {
```